# Increase simultaneous connection count for one user on IIS6

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis-6

By default one user can open only one simultaneous connection on IIS6, how to increase this number? I do not find any option in IIS6 for this.

Regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS doesn't limit the number of users, but the apps it runs might. Which application framework?

I've noticed ASP and possibly ASP.Net behave that way when you're using Sessions - if you disable ASP's session support, you can create multiple requests to the same page, unserialized.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such limit in IIS - the limit is on the browser side. For example, IE7 and Firefox 2 (by default) limit you to 2 simultaneous connections, IE8 and Firefox 3 to 6 simultaneous.

If you are seeing a limit of 1, then this was probably customized at some point. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402) Microsoft KB article about IE, and [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server) setting for Firefox.